# React-Native android: What are the persistent Storage options?

Tags: react-native

What is the closest thing to SQLite that I can get for React-Native android for persistent database storage for storing tables etc.

Thanks!

**Result**

- Realm (appears to be the better option.)
- react-native-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Realm](https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-react-native/) is an excellent solution for extended, relational storage in React Native. It's got great APIs for a number of RN components such as ListViews, and allows for powerful querying of datasets within your RN code.

As their website explains:

> Realm React Native is a true database for React Native, not just a
>   key-value store. Save regular objects with full object relationships,
>   and query them for always-live results. But none of this means you
>   give up on performance at all. Realm React Native is actually much
>   faster than alternatives!

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage. It's easy to use and implement.